# Python CGI replaces my html

Tags: python, html, cgi

I am teaching myself CGI with python and I am having trouble finding any references on how to just insert the output of the python program into my current html instead of replacing the whole existing page.

Here is  the python:

```
#!python
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

def loan(r, term, pv):
   if r is not None:
      r = float(r)
   if term is not None:
      term = float(term)
   if pv is not None:
      pv = float(pv)
   rate = r / 12
   numPeriods = 12 * term
   rate /= 100
   monthlyPayment = (pv * rate) / (1 - (1 + rate) ** (numPeriods * -1))
   return round(monthlyPayment, 2)

def getInput():
   r = form.getvalue("rate")
   term = form.getvalue("term")
   pv = form.getvalue ("amount")
   monthlyPayment = loan(r, term, pv)
   print("<p>Monthly Payment: %.2f<p>" % monthlyPayment)


print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"   
print """
<div>
<h1> Python CGI </h1>
<br />
 """

getInput()

print """
<br />
</div>
"""
```

And the HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Python CGI Test </title>
</head>
<body>

<h1> Mortage Loan Calculator CGI</h1>

<form action ="/cgi-bin/myPython.py" method ="get">

Rate: <input type = "text" name = "rate"/> <br />

Term: <input type = "text" name = "term"/> <br />

Amount <input type = "text" name = "amount"/> <br />

<button type = "submit" > submit </button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like the html from the python script to insert just below the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Server Side which means once the page is loaded, the only ways to reload content from Python is through reloading or AJAX. All the code will be run before the content is sent back to the user.

Comment: Yes, but how do I insert the content that the python script prints out into my current HTML instead of having what is returned through CGI replace my entire page? It could be possible that I don't actually understand the use of CGI, but would it not be able to be used like ajax to insert calculations made on a server to a webpage?

Comment: All these calculations can be done client side. There is no simple way to load server side content into the page without reloading it.

Comment: I see, so CGI would not really be used for insert into into a page but more for building new pages?

Comment: More like logging someone in, fetching database stuff or modifying the server. However, you can fetch server side calculations using AJAX.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could do that with AJAX. Would I be able to run the python script using javascript?

Comment: No, you would be able to run a Python file using AJAX then get the value it returns. JavaScript is unsafe. Anyone can run their own JavaScript on your website.